# show that the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^n}x^n$ is convergent for all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Show that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n^n}x^n$$ is convergent for  all $ x \in \mathbb{R} $. So guys so far I have attempted till this step :

$\frac{U_n+1}{U_n} = \frac{(2^{n+1})({x^{n+1}})}{{(n+1)^{n+1}}} \frac{n^n}{2^nx^n} = |2x|\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\frac{n}{n+1})^{n}\frac{1}{n+1}$.

I could further express the answer as :

$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}^n} \frac{1}{n+1}$, how is this appraching $0$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Why would anyone solve this for you? Read this thread ["How to ask a good question"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit your question accordingly to get the attention of others.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the repsonse. I tried using ratio test but I'm stuck at the end step

Comment: @Bumblebee hey thanks for the response, I was stuck in this Question. I will surely go through that hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the ratio test. $\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|= \dfrac{2^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\cdot \dfrac{n^n}{2^n}= \dfrac{2}{n+1}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\to 0 < 1$. Thus the series converges for all $x$.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response. How did you prove the last step. how is the whole expression approaching zero?

Comment: @GaurangChauhan: Hey, how are ya? it's a simple fact in calculus I that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e \approx 2.71728$ and $\dfrac{2}{n+1} \to 0$ hence the whole thing goes to $0$.

Comment: Thanks buddy, how are you?. great to see you. Yeah I did some research by limit multiplication property. Thanks again, makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ratio test $\frac{2x}{n}\to 0$ for all $x$ as $x\to \infty$.

Detail for ratio test:   Let $a_n=(\frac{2x}{n})^n$ we have $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\lt\frac{2x}{n}$, because $a_{n+1}\lt (\frac{2x}{n})^{n+1}$.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response.